# Trouble with creating a list of protein fragment sequences that corresponds with a list of their weights

Tags: list, dictionary, for-loop, python-itertools, biopython

This my code so far:

```
def weightcombinations(sequence, fragments):                            
#Calculating sequence weight
  for seq_rec in sequence:                                   
    seq_weight = 0.0                                                                                                               
    for i in seq_rec.seq:                                    
      seq_weight += SeqUtils.molecular_weight(i, "protein", circular = True)  
#Calculating the fragment weights  
    nums = []                                                
    for a in fragments:                                      
      fragment_weights = 0.0                                 
      for aa in a.seq:                                       
        fragment_weights += SeqUtils.molecular_weight(aa, 'protein', circular = True) 
      nums.append(round(fragment_weights, 2))                
#Creating list of weight combinations and list with the right combination of weights that sum to the seq_weight  
    weights_array = []                                       
    combs = [] 
    frags = []                                      
    if len(nums) > 0:                                                     
      for r in range(0,len(nums)+1):                         
          weights_array += list(combinations(nums, r))       
      for item in weights_array:                             
          if sum(item) == round(seq_weight, 2):                           
              combs.append(item)                             
#Print result    
    print("The protein sequence: " + seq_rec.seq)
    print("The molecular weight: " + str(round(seq_weight, 2)) + " Da.") 
    print(" ")                                       
    print("The possible combinations of fragment weights that may cover the protein sequence without overlap are: ")
    for row in combs:                                        
      print(*row, sep = ", ")

weightcombinations(seq_list3, seq_list4)
```

The output looks like this:

```
The protein sequence: IEEATHMTPCYELHGLRWVQIQDYAINVMQCL
The molecular weight: 3788.36 Da.
 
The possible combinations of fragment weights that may cover the protein sequence without overlap are: 
397.47, 2267.58, 475.63, 647.68
```

I was wondering how I could create a list of fragments that correspond with the combination of weights at the end of the output?
Something like this:

```
The protein sequence: IEEATHMTPCYELHGLRWVQIQDYAINVMQCL
The molecular weight: 3788.36 Da.
 
The possible combinations of fragments that may cover the protein sequence without overlap are: 
['AINV', 'IEEATHMTPCYELHGLRWV', 'MQCL', 'QIQDY']
and their respective molecular weights:
397.47, 2267.58, 475.63, 647.68
```

My intention was to append the correct sequences in the "frags" list. Or could there be a possibility to make a dictionary of the sequence as the key and the weight as the value?
I'm still pretty new to Python, so anything will help.
Thanks in advance and iff I need to give extra information, I'll comment back as fast as possible!

Comment: this is too much code, provide a [mcve]

Comment: So you want to look for each molecular weight index and retrieve the corresponding sequence?

Comment: Yes that's basically what I'm trying to achieve, but I'll also try to tidy up my code to make it more readable.

Comment: @iGian, I'm not good enough to minimize my code by a lot, but I tried to make it more readable and divide different actions. Hopefully this helps a little bit. Is there maybe a way to share the files that I'm using? That would also make it easier to help I assume.

Comment: The dictionary idea is reasonable. It seems this is a biopython question - I suggesting adding the tag, as well as the imports. Adding sample input/output might also be a good idea.

Comment: I made another post showing a smaller part of the code and the data that I want to work with. That should make it more clear what I'm trying to do.

Comment: we need at least one input sequence plus fragments just add them at the top of your code:  sequence = ['IEEATHMTPCYELHGLRWVQIQDYAINVMQCL']  fragments = ['AINV', 'IEEATHMTPCYELHGLRWV', 'MQCL', 'QIQDY']   .... auch these should be in seq_rec format !!!

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Dec 29 16:46:35 2020

@author: bob
"""

import Bio

from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord

from Bio import SeqUtils

from itertools import combinations 

sequence = [SeqRecord(Seq("IEEATHMTPCYELHGLRWVQIQDYAINVMQCL",),id="ENTIRE", name="ENTIRE",description="entrire protein")]


#['IEEATHMTPCYELHGLRWVQIQDYAINVMQCL'] 


#fragments = ['AINV', 'IEEATHMTPCYELHGLRWV', 'MQCL', 'QIQDY'] 

fragments = [SeqRecord(Seq("AINV",),id="FRAG_1", name="FRAG_1",description="FRAG_1"),
SeqRecord(Seq("IEEATHMTPCYELHGLRWV",),id="FRAG_2", name="FRAG_2",description="FRAG_2"),
SeqRecord(Seq("MQCL",),id="FRAG_3", name="FRAG_3",description="FRAG_3"),
SeqRecord(Seq("QIQDY",),id="FRAG_4", name="FRAG_4",description="FRAG_4")] 




def weightcombinations(sequence, fragments):                            
#Calculating sequence weight
  for seq_rec in sequence:                                   
    seq_weight = 0.0                                                                                                               
    for i in seq_rec.seq:                                    
      seq_weight += SeqUtils.molecular_weight(i, "protein", circular = True)  
#Calculating the fragment weights  
    nums = []                                                
    for a in fragments:                                      
      fragment_weights = 0.0                                 
      for aa in a.seq:                                       
        fragment_weights += SeqUtils.molecular_weight(aa, 'protein', circular = True) 
      nums.append(round(fragment_weights, 2))                
#Creating list of weight combinations and list with the right combination of weights that sum to the seq_weight  
    weights_array = []                                       
    combs = [] 
    frags = []                                      
    if len(nums) > 0:                                                     
      for r in range(0,len(nums)+1):                         
          weights_array += list(combinations(nums, r))       
      for item in weights_array:                             
          if sum(item) == round(seq_weight, 2):                           
              combs.append(item)                             
#Print result    
    print("The protein sequence: " + seq_rec.seq)
    print("The molecular weight: " + str(round(seq_weight, 2)) + " Da.") 
    print(" ")                                       
    print("The possible combinations of fragment weights that may cover the protein sequence without overlap are: ")
    for row in combs:                                        
      print(*row, sep = ", ")

weightcombinations(sequence, fragments)
```

this produces:

```
The protein sequence: IEEATHMTPCYELHGLRWVQIQDYAINVMQCL
The molecular weight: 3788.36 Da.
 
The possible combinations of fragment weights that may cover the protein sequence without overlap are: 
397.47, 2267.58, 475.63, 647.68
```